# How to forward to a named route?

Tags: symfony

How do I do forwarding a Symfony2 (2.2) class for which I do not know the name?

Please note, I do NOT want to redirect, since I must POST and I would prefer the POST parameters not to be sent via the browser.

The path's class is not obvious as it's the internal 'login_check'.

```
\\routing.yml
login: 
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller : MyAppBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern: /login_check

logout:
    pattern: /logout
```

If credentials are available from elsewhere, I want to just return a response as follows:

```
// SecurityController.php
... 
class SecurityController extends Controller{

    public function loginAction(){
       if($test_if_credentials_present){ 
           $response = $this->forward('login_check', 
              array('_username' => $username, '_password' => $password);
           return $response;
       }
    }
}
```

This fails as login_check is a route, not a class.

Is there some way to use router to find what class login_check corresponds to?

I could hard-code it also by knowing what the class name is from router:debug

```
php app/console router:debug login_check
```

Output:

```
[router] Route "login_check"
Name         login_check
Path         /login_check
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       ANY
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults
Requirements NO CUSTOM
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/login_check$#s
```

Thus, no class listed under Defaults.